# Capture parameters from url - angular

Tags: django, angularjs

I am writing an application using angular-django stack. For a page that displays a particular item's details at URL `items/<item-id>` I am loading template using django and want angular to load the actual item.

This page does not have any other state so it does not make sense to use routes. But in order to load data using angular I need to know the `<item-id>` from url. Is there a way to do that other than parsing url using $location service or something like that?

Comment: please, give us some code.

Answer (score 0):

I always just use vanilla javascript. This function will take in a parameter name and grab it's value. eg: url=http://example.com&param1=abcd

GetURLParameter(param1) would return "abcd"

```
var GetURLParameter = function (sParam) {
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Take use `$location.search()` by injecting $location dependency inside your controller or wherever you want to call this line of code, this will give you query string then

For specific parameter

```
$location.search().parameterName
```

Parameter name would be whatever you need from query string.

Inorder to work this you may need to activate html5mode in angular config phase.

Hope this could help you, Thanks.